# MongoDB node.js driver not running nor connecting to mongoDB server port 27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

Taking a tutorial on MongoDB so i am trying to work with the mongoDB driver. I use hyper terminal as my command line. I run "mongod" to start the mongoDB server then node app.js to run my app.js. At a point, i don't i dont get any response, eithger error nor succesfull, the terminal just remains static, then at a point when i run node app.js it logs "server running on port 3000" of which i dont have an app.listen anywhere in my app.js.

Here is my app.js file;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6UUL.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOaFu.png)

Below is my "mongod" command and logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqZk4.png)

Here is when i ran my app.js file with the static response;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEJ6q.png)

I expect to get a response like "connected successfully to server" "inserted 3 documents into the collection"

let me also share the "mongo" terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1vk7.png)

The fruitDB database wasn't created.

How do i troubleshoot this and achieve my aim here? Thanks

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Based on the pictures you do not connect to the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.